# How to SELECT multiple rows from same column optimally

Tags: sql, optimization

[**Student**] table

| pkid | FirstName |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | John |
| 02 | Mary |
| 03 | Kate |

[**CourseGrades**] table

| SID | courseName | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | maths | A |
| 01 | english | B |
| 01 | science | C |
| 01 | geography | D |
| 02 | english | C |
| 02 | science | B |
| 02 | geography | C |
| 03 | maths | B |
| 03 | english | E |
| 03 | geography | D |

[**CourseGrades**] is the master grade table where grades are just jotted down in no particular order and does not require any grades for students to be present.

Desired output:

| FirstName | MathsGrade | ScienceGrade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | A | C |
| Mary | NULL | B |
| Kate | B | NULL |

I'm currently using the query below to get my desired output.

```
SELECT 
    s.FirstName,
    cg1.Grade AS 'MathsGrade',
    cg2.Grade AS 'ScienceGrade',
FROM 
    [Student] s
LEFT JOIN 
    [CourseGrades] cg1 ON s.pkid = cg1.SID AND cg1.courseName = 'maths'
LEFT JOIN 
    [CourseGrades] cg2 ON s.pkid = cg2.SID AND cg2.courseName = 'science'
```

Is there a better (performance wise) way to select only maths and science grades for all students?

I need the output to show blank if the the student doesn't have the grade for that course. Which is why I'm using `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate and use CASE to weed out any grade that doesn't match the course.  This assumes that each student only has one grade.  If that's not the case, then you can't just use MAX().  There is FIRST_VALUE, but it is not going to work with nulls, and it's a little more verbose anyway.  See this fiddle (SQL Server 2019, you didn't specify):

https://dbfiddle.uk/?https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=05cf04d9a81d4660d7ce35a20f8c810f

```
SELECT s.FirstName,
  max(case when c.courseName = 'maths' then c.Grade else null end) as Maths,
  max(case when c.courseName = 'science' then c.Grade else null end) as Science
FROM Student s
LEFT JOIN CourseGrades c on s.pkid = c.sid
WHERE c.CourseName in ('maths', 'science')
GROUP BY s.FirstName;
```

You can remove the IN ('maths', 'science') clause.  It doesn't change the result.  It might make the query more efficient, but I don't think you're going to have enough data to worry about it.  So unless query optimization is part of the assignment, I think I'd just go with whatever was easier to write.

I am not sure that this approach is better than the one you have.  The left joins are cleaner reading than the case, even if you have to do them twice.  As far as performance, I'm going to switch the engine to mySQL for just a minute so I can use the json formatted explain there:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=457e42be15ae17b90a8a287614726605

You can see that the aggregate function without the WHERE clause is about 50% more costly (query_cost 3.80) than the one with it (2.10), but the two LEFT JOINs are about 17x more costly (34.05).

But again, there's not enough data to worry about performance.  I would stick with what's easiest to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'm only using the above tables as an example for my actual problem where the [CourseGrade] table has above 5k rows of data,9 cols and the query comprises of multiple table joins, which is why I'm trying to see if just this part could be optimized.

Comment: 5k rows is not very much data, to be honest.  I think most rdbms could handle that pretty easily without much optimization.  Are you having trouble with the queries now?  We currently have nearly 2 terabytes and make multiple joins for many operations, and we can still keep data fetches fast enough to face outward on a web application.  The indexing will probably be more impactful than trying to get the form exactly right, although that is important too.  Oh, also keeping the joined size of tables under system RAM is important.

Comment: Thanks for the extra tips, looks like aggregation and indexing is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve more performance you need to set those other columns as indexes as well and also optimise the query (this is specific to the database you are using, e.g. `ANALYSE ...`)